# kafka connector for "Ctrl+A" delimited files

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I learned to use Kafka connect to consume CSV files using the Confluent SpoolDir connector. Is there any way to use this connector (or does any other such connector exist) for "Ctrl+A" delimited files?

The records in the (source) files I want to use are separated by newline, whereas the columns are separated by "Ctrl+A".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this using the SpoolDir connector by creating a `SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector` and setting the `csv.separator.char=01` (01 is the ASCII for Ctrl-A) in file-source properties.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [file pulse connector](https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse) for ingesting the files. You'd just need to install it with the confluent tool  and set up the respective configuration.

You need to configure the [DelimitedRowFilter Filter](https://streamthoughts.github.io/kafka-connect-file-pulse/docs/developer-guide/filters/#delimitedrowfilter) to parse the CSV files accurately. It should be possible some how to use "Ctrl+A".

When everything is correctly set-up you can copy the CSV files into a given directory. In the configured time interval files are read and the content is copied into a topic.

Comment: Thankyou. I shall explore this. I was able to do the required task using the SpoolDir Connector itself, by setting the `csv.separator.char=01`.